# How to get music files of iphone using itunes sdk?

Tags: iphone, sdk, itunes

i'm researching to get music files in iphone.
i think i can get it using itunes sdk into PC based on windows, but i don't find a solution in sdk's document.
i can get playlists and music file's locations using sdk.

is it possible to get music and video files in iphone using itunes sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `AddMusic` example given by Apple:  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: i want to get it from iphone to PC. how to bring it to platform based on Windows?